# All the tags in [china]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

I don't see the utility of having a [china](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/china) tag (10 questions, no tag wiki). Most programming questions that seem to involve China in some way are actually questions about the [great-firewall-of-china](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/great-firewall-of-china) (59 questions) and should be retagged as such.

In general, we don't need location tags since programming is rarely location-specific, and even when it is, there is generally a better way to tag. We don't need a [switzerland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/switzerland), a [morocco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/morocco), or a [western-samoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/western-samoa), so I don't see why we need a [china](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/china).

Comment: Are you the bull in the `[china]` shop?

Comment: I agree, location tags are useless. We should burninate [java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java) as well ;)

Comment: Burninated.  You're welcome.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Isn't there supposed to be a process whereby users respond to the burninate-request, and users vote, and then action is taken once there's consensus?

Comment: @cigien only necessary if there's 50+ questions

Comment: @Nick Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @cigien Not just locations, why do we have tags for animals [python] and letters of the alphabet [c]? BURNINATE!!!!111!!

Comment: Why is this closed? I am confused. it isn't off-topic for the site, and if the burnination is complete, it should be tagged [tag:status-completed], no?

Comment: @RobertColumbia I don't see the use of you having Columbia in your name, no need to know your location and it seems a bit hypocritical based on your question

Comment: (Damn.  I was thinking of calling the next programming language I design "china" ... 'cos the implementation will be so fragile :-) )